# Magento2: Sharing link from our site, shows the og:name of an old site we had

Tags: magento2, link, social

I have 2 Magento websites in one Magento 2.4 backend.

Until recently, we had another website in the same backend, but we deactivated it.

When I share a link from 1 of the remaining active sites in Telegram, it shows the name of the deactivated site. We have spent many hours looking for the location where Telegram gets this info from, but so far without result.

The URL is from alpineopticsusa.com, but it additionally shows the no longer active and unrelated carmodelz.com.

Any help on how to make sure only the relevant info is shown is highly appreciated.

[image: Image showing the shared URL and the name of a different old website]

Comment: Hi @Rob, Did you try it again? Is it working fine?

Comment: Indeed I tried again, also updated the Telegram Bot, but it didn't change anything. The old website is still shown.

Comment: ROb, I just updated my answer. Please check it once. It should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the link in telegram,

For info the preview is based on :

og:image, og:title and og:description

You can use the online tool to update your link

https://telegram.me/webpagebot

Source : https://support.wix.com/en/article/updating-your-pages-link-preview-in-telegram

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I tried this, but it didn't work so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked reviewed your website/store tags & they are correctly configured. like `og:title` `og:url` `og:image`. But I found that there is one more tag `og:site_name` that is showing old website URL.

**Here is the tag showing to your website:**

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Carmodelz.com"/>
```

**Please check the below screenshot:**

[image]

Please update this tag with the current website/store URL. and after that verify it on telegram.

**I tested the below URL:**

https://www.alpineopticsusa.com/us/cryptocurrency

I would suggest please double verify/update all the `og:` meta tags as per the current website/store.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, but unfortunately after using the Telegram bot link update the wrong site is still shown.

[image: No difference after updating the link in the Telegram bot]

Comment: Rob, I just updated my answer. Please check it once. It should fix your issue.